# Проблема в регулярном выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Не могу сделать так, чтобы работало. Вот простое выражение:

```
var re = new RegExp('\[img*\]abcde\[/img\]','gim');
alert(re.test('[img=600x399]abcde[/img]'));
```

Пишет false. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7Ner/). Что нужно исправить?

Comment: > Что нужно исправить?

Учебник или хотя бы краткий справочник по регекспам почитать?

Например, вы можете объяснить (в первую очередь самому себе), что значит вот эта звёздочка и зачем она тут написана: `\[img*\]`

Comment: @klopp, Спасибо, разобрался с символами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var re = /\[img=.*?\]abcde\[\/img\]/gim;
alert(re.test('[img=600x399]abcde[/img]'));
```

---

```
var re = new RegExp("\\[img=.*?\\]abcde\\[\\/img\\]", "gim");
alert(re.test('[img=600x399]abcde[/img]'));
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7Ner/1/), [JsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/E7Ner/2/)**

Comment: Хм, а если делать через new RegExp, то почему то не работает. Мне нужно чтобы можно было подставить переменную.

Comment: @rimlin, обновил ответ